# Issue with average function

Tags: python, function, output, average

I checked that this average code works:

```
final = (sum(num)/len(num))
```

But for some reason when I use my whole function.

```
def average(num):
    final = (sum(num)/len(num))
    return(final)
num = []
for x in range(5):
    num.append(int(input("Please enter a number. ")))

print(num)
print(average)
```

**It outputs this: <function average at 0x0000027D09927F70>**

I don't know why it doesn't just output the average number?

Sorry I am not great at coding.

Comment: Be aware that your `average` function will fail with `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero` if an empty list is passed to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't call the function, you printed the function itself instead.
Try it like that:

```
def average(num):
    final = (sum(num)/len(num))
    return(final)
num = []
for x in range(5):
    num.append(int(input("Please enter a number. ")))

print(num)
print(average(num)) #Edited this
```

Comment: To further clarify: the `num` local variable (in `num = []`) and the `num` parameter (in `average(num)`) are completely unrelated variables, that just happen to share the same name (but live in different scopes, so there's no conflict or ambiguity)

Answer (score 1):

you should pass the parameter num to the average function on the last line

```
print(average(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to print the function itself and not the value returned by the function.

You can call a function by appending the desired parameter(s) in parenthesis. Exactly as you are using `sum(num)` and `len(num)`.